# Why do my network interface and powered-off backlight consume too much power in powertop?

Tags: networking, laptop, display, power, backlight

I have an ASUS n550jv laptop. Currently, the wifi is off, the ethernet is active, and the display is completely off (using an external monitor). Yet, in powertop I see the following:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 12.3 W
System baseline power is estimated at 87.1 mW

Power est.    Usage     Device name
  5.16 W     19.1 pkts/s  Network interface: p3p1 (r8169)
  3.37 W      0.0%        Display backlight
  3.37 W      0.0%        Display backlight
  3.37 W      0.0%        Display backlight
  981 mW     10.4%        CPU misc
  844 mW     10.4%        DRAM
  363 mW     10.4%        CPU core
  270 mW    100.0%        USB device: USB2.0-CRW (Generic)
  116 mW     35.7 ops/s   GPU misc
 43.9 mW     35.7 ops/s   GPU core
```

How can the display backlight consume 10W when it's not powered on? Is this a bug in powertop? The total power consumed is correct, my battery discharge rate agrees with this.

The network interface surely shouldn't consume 5W of power - this must be a bug somewhere.

Any ideas for fixing this or what to test to see what's really consuming the power?

Edit: The USB device: USB2.0-CRW (Generic) device (SD card reader) likes to consume about 1W, even though there's no card.

Comment: How would you know what is too much? Are you an electrical/electronics engineer? Did you design the laptop? Making statements like `it's using too much power` implies that you know precisely how much power it should be consuming and can therefore determine that it's using too much. Saying `it's using too much power` because it's using `some` power isn't a quantifiable or a qualified statement.

Comment: Dude. It's an LED that's turned off. 10W is too much, in that it's greater than zero. Likewise, typical power usage for a ethernet interface in heavy use is maybe 1-2W, certainly not 40% of a laptop's total power consumption.

Comment: I'm just saying that unless you designed those components you have no idea what their power consumption should be while they're on or off. LED and LCD panels still consume power when `off`.

Comment: That's fair, and if another ASUS n550 user confirms that this is the best we can do, or those numbers are in a spec sheet somewhere, I'd accept that answer. I don't believe that's the case, though. I suspect either powertop is mis-assigning the power consumed from another device or there's a bug in a driver or OS setting somewhere.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I'm not an electrical engineer, but my C720 uses an LED backlight. When you pass a current through an LED, it lights up. The screen is completely black, so the backlight is definitely completely off. Therefore, no current is passing through the LED. This means that either: The display is on, even though the backlight is off; the display is badly designed, and when "`off`" functions as a heater; powertop is buggy; or pixies are stealing your power.

Comment: Those wattage readings are experimental. If they work, great. If not, no surprise.